# How can I get the property names of a class without having an instance of the class?

Tags: javascript, reflection

I have a class:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

How can I get the properties `height` and `width` as strings without having an instance of `Rectangle`?

Comment: I believe it will be restricted. As a workaround maybe it will fit you: convert to string and parse?

Comment: Given that JavaScript has no notion of "THE properties of a class" and the OP appears to be asking for the fields assigned to in the constructor, then I'd be totally shocked if there was a way other than parsing the constructor. But that said, think of all the nastiness that could be written in a constructor: it's arbitrary JavaScript! @Saravana what are you trying to do with this info? You do know there is nothing at all special about the constructor-assigned properites, because more can be added at any time. JavaScript does not have fixed, closed, classes (they're just functions anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to create an empty instance on-the-fly at least:

```js
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}

console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(new Rectangle))
```